# Troubles with ParallelEvaluate

Tags: parallelization

I need to evaluate the same expression on all subkernels just like ParallelEvaluate does.
This code distributes perfectly (2 kernels):

```
LaunchKernels[]
ParallelEvaluate[

i = 1;
count = 0;
While[i > 0, 
{count = count + 1;
i = i + 1}
]
];
```

[image]

But if i declare a funcion either in package or in notebook only one kernel works:

```
myCycle := (
i = 1;
count = 0;
While[i > 0, 
{count = count + 1;
 i = i + 1}
]
);

LaunchKernels[]

ParallelEvaluate[myCycle]
```

[image]

How can i make my own methods work in parallel?
Thank you!

Comment: Hi Sasha, welcome to Mathematica.SE, please consider taking the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) so you learn the basic rules of the site. Thanks for sharing you code in a well [formatted form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help). Probably you need to use [`DistributeDefinitions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DistributeDefinitions.html)?